# Когда переходить на использование ООП в PHP?

Tags: ооп, php

Нормально себя чувствую в процедурном стиле, когда стоит переходить на использование ООП в PHP? Нужно хорошо научиться в процедурном стиле программировать или можно уже на ООП переходить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучше уже прямо сейчас переходите на ООП, а потом когда хорошо освоите ООП можете изучить какой-нибудь ООП framework! Сначала могут возникнуть некоторые трудности перехода на ООП, но потом Вы поймете преимущества использования ООП перед процедурным программированием.